# error in compiling xcbproto 1.7

Tags: linux

I tried to compile xcbproto 1.7 in linux and get an error message when type make install command

```
Making install in xcbgen
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/reham/miriad_files/xcb-proto-1.7/xcbgen'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/reham/miriad_files/xcb-proto-1.7/xcbgen'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
test -z "/usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/xcbgen" || /bin/mkdir -p "/usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/xcbgen"
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 __init__.py error.py expr.py matcher.py state.py xtypes.py '/usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/xcbgen'
/home/reham/Desktop/Fermi/ScienceTools-v9r15p2-fssc-20090808-i686-pc-linux-gnu-libc2.5/i686-pc-linux-gnu-libc2.5/bin/python: error while loading shared libraries: libpython2.5.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** [install-pkgpythonPYTHON] Error 127
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/reham/miriad_files/xcb-proto-1.7/xcbgen'
make[1]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/reham/miriad_files/xcb-proto-1.7/xcbgen'
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there's a problem with a custom python version you seem to have installed on your system. Namely this one:

```
/home/reham/Desktop/Fermi/ScienceTools-v9r15p2-fssc-20090808-i686-pc-linux-gnu-libc2.5/i686-pc-linux-gnu-libc2.5/bin/python
```

This seems to depend on the shared library `libpython2.5.so.1.0` which isn't found by the linker.

Most probably the custom python version you installed brought this shared library along and it just isn't found as it is not in one of the standard directories.

To fix this you might either try to use the python version installed on your system or add the path containing `libpython2.5.so.1.0` to the ones searched by the linker.

My guess is it will be somewhere below  `/home/reham/Desktop/Fermi/ScienceTools-v9r15p2-fssc-20090808-i686-pc-linux-gnu-libc2.5/i686-pc-linux-gnu-libc2.5/`

Most probably in the subdirectory `/lib` .

Comment: The shared library libpython2.5.so.1.0 is below /home/reham/Desktop/Fermi/ScienceTools-v9r15p2-fssc-20090808-i686-pc-linux-gnu-libc2.5/i686-pc-linux-gnu-libc2.5/lib

Comment: But how can I add this path?

Comment: Setting the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to this directory should enable the dynamic linker to find it. Try using `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=wherever/it/is` prior to your call to make.